# returning MyBatis resultMap as map

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have a mybatis resultMap refer to a POJO class as like below.

```
<resultMap id="FolderResultMap" type="Folder">
    <result column="recordcount"  property="recordCount" />
    <result column="contenttype"  property="folderContentType"  />
    <result column="folderid"  property="folderId"  />
    <result column="folderdesc"  property="folderDescription"  />
    <result column="foldername"  property="folderName"  />
    <result column="foldertype"  property="folderType"  />
</resultMap>

<select id="findReportFolders" resultMap="FolderResultMap">
    some query
</select>
```

And in my Mapper interface

```
List<Folder> findReportFolders (@Param("name") long id,
                                   @Param("id2") long busid);
```

Because of this i am getting JSON response as list of objects where i need map of list of objects as below mentioned.

```
    {
  "folders": [
    {
      "recordCount": 7,
      "folderContentType": "Reports",
      "folderId": 139491,
      "folderDescription": null,
      "folderName": "AA_TestPrivateFolder1234",
      "folderType": "CUSTOM",
      "refreshable": true
    },
    {
      "recordCount": 35,
      "folderContentType": "Reports",
      "folderId": 140109,
      "folderDescription": "Default Folder for New Reports",
      "folderName": "label.privateReportInboxOverrideName",
      "folderType": "INBOX",
      "refreshable": true
    }]
    }
```

This what i am getting now. I would like to get the response as above.

```
[{"folderId":359056,"folderName":"BE Shared Report Inbox","folderDescription":"BE Shared Report Inbox","folderType":"INBOX","folderContentType":"SharedReports","recordCount":0,"refreshable":true},{"folderId":363984,"folderName":"Default Inbox Folder","folderDescription":"Default Folder for New Reports","folderType":"INBOX","folderContentType":"Reports","recordCount":0,"refreshable":true}]
```

Any Idea how can i do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. First of all, mybatis does not create JSON for you. You get the list of `Folder`s from the mapper and then you do something to get JSON. How do you do that? Are you looking to the output of serialization of that list that spring MVC does for you? The next question is what is format you are getting now and what do you want to get, please include both.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your example JSON requires a Map of anything.
Instead,
create an object hierarchy that represents the JSON structure that you need and use Jackson (or some other JSON library) to generate the JSON.

Here is some example code that uses Jackson:

```
package blam.won;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Blam
{
  @JsonProperty
  private String folderContentType;

  @JsonProperty
  private int recordCount;

  public void setFolderContentType(
    final String newValue)
  {
    folderContentType = newValue;
  }

  public void setRecordCount(
    final int newValue)
  {
    recordCount = newValue;
  }
}


package blam.won;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Kapow
{
  @JsonProperty("folders")
  private List<Blam> blamList;

  public void setBlamList(
    final List<Blam> newValue)
  {
    blamList = newValue;
  }
}


package blam.won;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestWon
{
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Before
  public void preTestSetup()
  {
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  }

  @Test
  public void testKapow()
    throws JsonProcessingException
  {
    final Blam blam1 = new Blam();
    final Blam blam2 = new Blam();
    final List<Blam> blamList = new LinkedList<>();
    final String jsonString;
    final Kapow kapow = new Kapow();

    blam1.setFolderContentType("Reports");
    blam1.setRecordCount(7);
    blamList.add(blam1);

    blam2.setFolderContentType("Reports");
    blam2.setRecordCount(35);
    blamList.add(blam2);

    kapow.setBlamList(blamList);

    jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(kapow);

    System.out.println(jsonString);
  }
}
```